# Array formulas that do not use explicit ranges

Tags: excel, array-formulas

For every instance of a customer buying a product I need to figure out when that customer previously bought that product. I've a solution that works using array formulas:

```
{=MAX(IF(($D$3:$D$15 = [@Product])*($C$3:$C$15=[@Customer]) * ($E$3:$E$15<[@Date]),$E$3:$E$15,FALSE))}
```

and I like it because it doesn't require that the data be sorted (I wanted to avoid that prerequisite) but I am not totally happy about it because the formula includes cell ranges (e.g. `$D$3:$D$15`) and hence if and when new transactions are added to the source data I'll need to update the formula.

A worked example is [here](http://1drv.ms/1QIwjg3) on OneDrive.

[image]

Can anyone figure out a better way of doing this that can do away with those ranges in the array formula?

Comment: Search for "Excel dynamic range offset". Sorry to be so short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using structured references instead of the range ref

{=MAX(IF((Table1[[#All],[Product]] = [@Product])*(Table1[[#All],[Customer]]=[@Customer]) * (Table1[[#All],[Date]]<[@Date]),Table1[[#All],[Date]],FALSE))}

Comment: That works too. Thank you @Charles-Williams. I never understood the difference between (e.g.) [Date] & [@Date]. Now (I think) I do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another condition to the date retrieval would be easier (and non-array) is switched over to the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) where any non-matching value is forced to an error and errors are ignored.

```
' in F3
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14, 6, ([Date])/(([Product]=[@Product])*([Customer]=[@Customer])*([Date]<[@Date])), 1), "")
' in G3
=IF([@PreviousPurchase]="", "", [@Date]-[@PreviousPurchase])
```

[image: Last purchase date]

The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) returns a zero-length string (e.g. `""`) when no previous purchase date can be determined. This requires that the G3 formula be adjusted as as well.

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Sample returned to: http://1drv.ms/1gwJ8wH

Comment: Awesome. Didn't know about AGGREGATE. WIll go and read up on it now. Thanks @Jeeped .